# Phoenix.View.render_to_string How render template with layout?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Render for template works fine:

```
html = Phoenix.View.render_to_string(MyApp.BillingView, "receipt.html", %{organization: organization, transaction: transaction})
```

...but I would like to render this view with a layout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Solution:
`Phoenix.View.render_to_string(MyApp.BillingView, "receipt.html", [organization: organization, transaction: transaction, layout: {MyAppWeb.LayoutView, "receipt.html"}, conn: conn])`
It occurs that I didn't assign @conn.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Feel free to answer your own question with an actual answer if you solved it yourself. It's more helpful to people in the future, and comments aren't the place for answers. Also, the [Help] is a great resource to learn better how the site works!